# How to use Material Icons Symbols with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, material-icons

How do we set the `fontSet` attribute on `MatIcon` in order to get the Material Symbols to render.

I'm trying to render the [`expand_content` symbol](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Symbols%20Outlined%3Aexpand_content%3AFILL%400%3Bwght%40400%3BGRAD%400%3Bopsz%4024) however it is not rendering as shown in the material icons font.

This is the markup for rendering it as a `span` element:

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
expand_content
</span>
```

This is how Angular Renders it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lgahav?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html

This is the markup:

```
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined">expand_content</mat-icon>
```

And this is the icon I'm trying to render.

[image]

Comment: hmm i can see the icon rendered in the stackblitz

Comment: @Yogi Yes indeed I'm looking for it to render the expand icon in the link you shared.

Comment: Indeed.  The `fontSet` attribute is usually used to control which icon is rendered and how, so I'm sure if it has the correct value, the icon will render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `material-symbols-outlined` to `mat-icon` like this.

```
 <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">expand_content</mat-icon>
```

[There's notes on this in this issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24845).

[Also there's an NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-symbols) with more detailed instructions for Material Symbols use in general.

Comment: Oh - I see what you mean.  Funny it renders the same icon in both cases.  I updated the question with a picture of the icon that I'm trying to render.  It's also in the documentation link and has the URL for importing the symbol icons.

Comment: I found an issue containing the solution and I updated your answer with it.